# Between Pagination

Tags: php, pagination

Help me, i was writing my code, all done succesfully but my problem is when the "..." (separator) for my curerent page and last page showed after the **last** page, not **between** my current page and my last page 
[image]

how can that possible ?
this is my script for showing the page :

```
<?php
$paging2 = mysqli_query($koneksi,"select * from laporan where seksi='{$seksi}'");
$jmldata = mysqli_num_rows($paging2);
$jmlhalaman = ceil($jmldata/$batas);

echo "<ul class='pagination'>";

if ($halaman !== 1){
  echo  "<li><a href='index.php?load=table_laporan&halaman=1'>First</a></li>";
}
if ($halaman > 1){
  echo  "<li><a href='index.php?load=table_laporan&halaman=".($halaman-1)."'>Previous</a></li>";
}
for($i =1; $i <= $jmlhalaman; $i++){
if ((($i >= $halaman - 3) && ($i <= $halaman + 3)) || ($i == 1) || ($i ==$jmlhalaman)) 
{ 
if ($i == $halaman){
$class="active";
} else{
$class="disable";
}  //echo "<b>$i</b>"; 
echo "<li class='$class'><a href=\"index.php?load=table_laporan&halaman=".$i."\">".$i."<span class='sr-only'>(current)</span></a></li>";
if($i==$jmlhalaman && $halaman <= $jmlhalaman-5) echo "<li><a>...</a></li>"; 
if($i==1 && $halaman >= 6) echo "<li><a>...</a></li>"; 

  }
 }
 if ($halaman >= 1){ 
  echo  "<li><a href=index.php?load=table_laporan&halaman=". ($halaman+1)."'>Next</a></li>";
 } if ($halaman >= 1){
  echo  "<li><a href='index.php?load=table_laporan&halaman=". ($jmlhalaman)."'>Last</a></li>";
 }

 echo "</ul>";
 echo "<p>Total Data : <b>$jmldata</b> Data</p>";
 ?>
```

Comment: Do you want to remove the ... after page 1?

Comment: @adlan-ak You need to add condition to check whether the page is last or next page does not exists and based on that condition, not to show ...

Comment: @adlan-ak You can also calculate total number of pages earlier and then add a condition.

Comment: Move this line - `if($i==$jmlhalaman && $halaman <= $jmlhalaman-5) echo "<li><a>...</a></li>";` to before your `echo "<li class='$class'>...`. as you want the `14|17|...` to be `14|...|17`, not after.

Comment: thank u so much @sean, i got all my promblem fixed ! case closed.